# Question about elements in set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I just have a question about this.
Let A = {(2, 5),(−3, 1),(4, 2),(1, 1),(0, 1)}
List the elements of the following sets.
The only one I can't figure out is this:
{a1 | (a1, a2) ∈ A, a1 > a2}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the issue with this?. a1 is the first component of (a1,a2) and a2 is second. Just compare them for all elements in the given set.

Answer (score 1):

In words, $\{a_1\mid (a_1,a_2)\in A,~a_1>a_2\}$ is the set of all first elements of a pair in $A$ such that said first element is bigger than the second element in the same pair.

$(2,5)$ was in $A$ but $2$ is not bigger than $5$, so we do not include $2$ in our set.

$(-3,1)$ is in $A$ but $-3$ is not bigger than $1$, so we do not include $-3$ in our set.

$\vdots$

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense. Thank you!